# Which is the right subordinate Certificate Authorities (CAs) utilized by Azure while connecting to the IoT Hub?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, azure-iot-hub, x509certficiate2

This question is regarding the critical changes to the certificate (Baltimore to DigiCert migration)

As per https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things-blog/azure-iot-tls-critical-changes-are-almost-here-and-why-you/ba-p/2393169  , we need to include below certificate.

[image]

However, In this article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/security/fundamentals/azure-ca-details?tabs=root-and-subordinate-cas-list it shows as different thumbprint

[image]

So I want to know, which is the right certificate to be included in the devices so that it can successfully connect to the Azure IoT Hub?

Answer (score 1):

Although I also don't understand why the thumbprint doesn't match. You can find the certificate with the correct thumbprint on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/security/fundamentals/azure-ca-details?tabs=certificate-authority-chains) page.

Comment: How are you sure that this page has the right information? Is there a way to check connectivity using this certificate?